# how to register and install hook in prestashop 1.7?

Tags: module, hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have added one module hook manage box in PrestaShop 1.7 . Module is installed and i have created one hook called dispalybeforehome but it is not showing me in my module. how to register it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your module during the installation, with the `install` method you should add this snippet:

```
$this->registerHook('displayBeforeHome');
```

For example:

```
public function install()
{
    return parent::install() and $this->registerHook('displayBeforeHome');
}
```

Then you have to create the `hookDisplayBeforeHome` method in your module:

```
public function hookDisplayBeforeHome($params)
{
    // do your stuff
    return 'IT WORKS!';
}
```

Then in the template add the smarty snippet to call the hook:

```
{hook h='displayBeforeHome'}
```

That's all ;)

Comment: @Bhu Obviously XD